# Passenger side locking

Tags: honda, brakes, fit

Help! My front passenger brake is locking!!.
After a short time of driving the passenger side brake is locking.

Rotor disc was bow - replaced

After rotor disc was replaced both breaks were locking - Replaced Calibre - Replaced Hose - Replaced Brakes - Bled Brakes.

Now! Only passenger side brake is locking. 
What's the issue now. Haha.

Honda Fit 2004.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Were the caliper slider pins checked for ease of motion?